# How can one approach the question of internalization of sets using external functions?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

This question is along the same general line of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389441/can-this-theory-that-internalize-sets-from-external-functions-be-consistent) one, but it is formulated in ZF milieu.

We add a total one place function symbol $``f"$ to the language of ZF.

Then add the following axioms on top of ZF axioms ($``f"$ not allowed in separation and collection):

**Injectivity:** $\forall x \, \forall y: f(x)=f(y) \to x=y$

**Downward :** $ \exists \alpha \, \exists \beta:  f `` V_\alpha = V_{\beta+1} \land \lim(\alpha) \land \lim(\beta) \land \beta < \alpha $

Where $f``k= \{f(x): x \in k\}$

**Internalization:** $\forall x \subseteq V_\alpha \, \exists y: y =\{f(z): z \in x\} \\ \forall x \subseteq V_{\beta+1} \, \exists y: y=\{z: f(z) \in x\}$

In English: we have an external injective function on the universe that setwisely moves a rank $V_\alpha$ dowardly to a proper subset of it $V_{\beta+1}$ where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are limit ordinals. So internally the theory see $V_{\beta+1}$ extremely strictly smaller than $V_\alpha$ but externally $f \restriction V_\alpha$ is a bijection between them! Now the internalization axiom would internalize every image of a subset of $V_\alpha$ under $f$, and also every pre-image of a subset of $V_{\beta+1}$ under $f$. This internalization is supposed to *add* sets to these stages, since it uses an external symbol that is not used in separation and collection that built them in the first place. However, I'm not sure if this is consistent. Anyhow, it appears to be a very hard question.

> How can I go about proving the consistency (or inconsistency) of such a result? Any reference to similar situations?  Had that question been posed before? And if so what are the known partial (or final) results about it?

I know for example that all of the above axioms would hold if I remove the condition of $\alpha$ being a limit ordinal, so $\alpha$ can be $\gamma +1$ for some limit $\gamma > \beta$, and we can take $f$ to be an automorphism on the universe, and internalization is known to hold. But here we have a difference in parity of the indexing ordinals and this would serve to preculde that approach.

Comment: A forcing argument should do this: we build an $f:V_\alpha\rightarrow V_{\beta+1}$ via conditions consisting of a finite approximation to $f$ *together with* finitely many rules of the form "$\{f(z): z\in x\}=y$" and "$\{z: f(z)\in x\}=y$" satisfying the obvious consistency conditions. The details are a bit messy (hence this comment as opposed to an answer) but I don't think anything difficult happens.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, so you generally think this is most likely consistent? So, the general attack against such a question is through forcing! Had there been a similar question, I mean closely near to this one that is known to be solved through forcing, so that one can in some sense parrot its footsteps.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, which kind of forcing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_forcing_notions, it seems that Levy forcing is near to this since it is about cardinalities???

Comment: Like I said in my original comment, it's not exactly any of the "basic" forcing notions. Conditions are (function, rule) pairs with certain properties. If I get a chance later on I'll write it up.